# iOS Method Call With Animation, Perform Action on Completion?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

When programming for iOS, I frequently find myself faced with the following situation:

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    [self performSomeAnimation];

    //below is an action I want to perform, but I want to perform it AFTER the animation
    [self someAction];
}

- (void)performSomeAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^
    {
        //some animation here
    }];
}
```

Faced with this situation, I usually end up just copy/pasting my animation code so that I can use the completion block handler, like so:

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    [self performSomeAnimation];


    //copy pasted animation... bleh
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^
    {
        //same animation here... code duplication, bad.
    }
    completion^(BOOL finished)
    {
        [self someAction];
    }];
}

- (void)performSomeAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^
    {
        //some animation here
    }];
}
```

What is the proper way to solve this problem?  Should I be passing a block of code to my `-(void)performSomeAction` method, like below, and executing that block on completion of the animation?

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    block_t animationCompletionBlock^{
        [self someAction];
    };

    [self performSomeAnimation:animationCompletionBlock];
}

- (void)performSomeAnimation:(block_t)animationCompletionBlock
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^
    {
        //some animation here
    }
    completion^(BOOL finished)
    {
        animationCompletionBlock();
    }];
}
```

Is that the proper way to solve this problem?  I guess I have been avoiding it because I'm not THAT familiar with block usage (not even sure if I declared that block properly) and it seems like a complicated solution to a simple problem.

Comment: You're saying the animation is always the same, but the completion changes? If so, your solution looks like a good one to me.

Comment: I think my syntax isn't correct though.  I just looked into it and I should declare my block like so: void (^myBlock) (void),  but what would my method declaration look like?  - (void)performSomeAnimation:(void)(^myBlock)(void) didn't seem to work (I'm sure I'm butchering that syntax haha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this:

```
- (void)performSomeAnimationWithCompletion:(void(^)(void))animationCompletionBlock
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^
    {
        //some animation here
    }
    completion^(BOOL finished)
    {
        animationCompletionBlock();
    }];
}
```

And instead of explicitly defining a block and passing it as parameter, you can call it directly like this (this is how block animations work for UIView, for example):

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    [self performSomeAnimationWithCompletion:^{

        [self someAction];

    }];
}
```

Comment: Hmmm okay.  This might be even better than trying to create a block and pass it using the method I was trying.  It seems a bit cleaner and feels more natural for some reason.

Comment: yeah it is a bit cleaner. for these sort of things blocks are really helpful. don't be afraid to use them!

Comment: Already added this into my code and everything appears to be working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, it seems that you already pretty much have the answer, you just need to delete the first call to     performSomeOperation    :

```
- (void)someMethod
```

{

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^
{
    //Your animation block here
}
completion: ^(BOOL finished)
{
    //Your completion block here
    [self someAction];
}];
```

}

Comment: Well, the issue (as Josh put much more elegantly than I did) is that I have an animation I perform that is always the same, but the completion block constantly changes, so I needed a way to pass a completion block so as not to be constantly duplicating my animation code.